# git_revwalk ignores order of pushed refs?

Tags: git, libgit2, objective-git

In using `git_revwalk` (through Objective-Git's `GTEnumerator`), I'm trying to get more recently updated branches ordered first. I'm calling `gt_revwalk_push` with refs sorted by commit date, but it has no effect. Sorted, reverse sorted, and unsorted all come out the same.

Using `GIT_SORT_TIME` without `GIT_SORT_TOPOLOGICAL` comes close, but I do need a topological ordering, so I'm setting both flags.

Is there a way to get `git_revwalk` to use the refs in the order I give them?

Comment: I know nothing of Objective-Git but asking for a topo sort *and* a time-based sort is like asking for 1 PM to come before noon because 1 is less than 12.  You must give up on one of these two criteria: you can't get both.

Comment: With both flags, I would expect commits from parallel branches to be sorted relative to each other. That would be possible to a limited extent without violating topological order. But anyway, that's tangential to my real problem. I would expect, for example, that the newest commit should come out first since that's the ref that I pushed first, and that's not happening.

Comment: ...of course, that's assuming that the first ref points to a commit with no children, which it does in my test case.

Comment: True, you can use one as a secondary sort criterion when the first criterion produces a tie. Topo has to go first to have any meaning at all, so this merely picks which edge to traverse depth-first based on sorting the outgoing edges by node time-stamps. With Git, that means sorting the parents by author or committer date. (Note that outgoing edges are *parent* links, not *child* links.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libgit2 would often not provide quite the same topological sorting as git, since there are multiple possible topological sortings which are all correct.

[A recent PR](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/3921) ported over more code from git to make the output more consistent for other reasons, so you make use of that. Specifying both a topological and time-based sort (`GIT_SORT_TOPOLOGICAL | GIT_SORT_TIME`), equivalent to `git rev-list`'s `--date-order` will sort the tips you requested by time with the current `master`.

Comment: I finally got a chance to try this out, and it works great.